# Angular 9 : use external js script with condition

Tags: javascript, java, angular, angular8, angular9

I'm new with Angular 9.

I have an external js script, I got the url of this script from the back-end side by using the meta tag. I have a function return a boolean, I want when this method return true I call the script and if it's false nothing to do.

I read the url from the backend by :

```
  <meta name="myScriptUrl" content="URLSCRIPT">
```

In app.component.ts I create 2 methods one to get the url of the script and the other return a boolean

```
public getUrlScrip(): string {
  return this.configurationService.getConfig('myScriptUrl');
}
public isCheck(): boolean {
  return (this.model.specificTest === anyString);
}
```

Thisthe specific component (insert-js.component.ts) that could I use the script,

```
@Component
export class insertJs implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

public usrlScript: string;

constructor(
  private readonly appComponent: AppComponent;
}

ngOnInit() {
  if (this.appComponent.isCheck) {
    usrlScript = this.appComponent.getUrlScrip();
  }
```

This is the insert-js.component.html

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="urlScript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        //set variable in the script
    }, {once: true});
  </script>
```

Thank's to give me some idea to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can try Renderer2 this way:-

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){}

addScriptToElement(src: string): HTMLScriptElement {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = src;
  this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, script);
  //use removeChild to remove the added tag on your condition
  return script;
}
```

Call this function this way :-

```
this.addScriptToElement('https://widgets.skyscanner.net/widget-server/js/loader.js').onload = () => {
        console.log('Loaded SkyScanner tag successfully!');
}
```